# In what possible situation can NumberFormatter.string return nil?

Tags: ios, swift

I have just a curiosity question about what possible situation a `NumberFormatter.string` can return a nil.

Say I have the below code

```
    let nf = NumberFormatter()
    nf.numberStyle = .currency
    nf.currencyCode = "USD"
    let myVal = 100.23
    let resultString: String? = nf.string(from: myVal as NSNumber)
```

In what situation would `resultString` be nil?

Apple Docs: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/numberformatter/1418046-string